# Different results from MD5 libraries

Tags: node.js, npm, hash, md5

I need to hash some data using MD5. I wanted to test the performance of difference libraries. However, I'm noticing that I'm getting different hashes of the same data, depending upon which library is being used:

```
Generating data...

Hashing data with 'md5' library...
         Hash: 1b37c84ebc8426e19d3b1797b6e320c6
         Duration: 0.848s

Hashing data with 'object-hash' library...
         Hash: f046296e8016b5632e6a1d1ebc885892
         Duration: 0.032s

Hashing data with 'create-hash' library...
         Hash: 1b37c84ebc8426e19d3b1797b6e320c6
         Duration: 0.023s
```

I would have expected the same hash to be shown for both libraries. Any ideas? My code is below...

```
const generateData = () => {
    console.log('Generating data...')
    let data = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        data += "1234567890";
    }
    console.log()    
    return data;
}

const convertToUInt8Array = (s) => {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2)
    {
        result.push(parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
    }
    result = Uint8Array.from(result)
    return result;
}

const hashData = (name, hashingFunction, data) => {
    console.log(`Hashing data with '${name}' library...`)
    const start = new Date()
    const hash = hashingFunction(data)
    const end = new Date()
    console.log(`\t Hash: ${hash}`)
    const duration = (end - start) / 1000
    console.log(`\t Duration: ${duration}s`)
    console.log()
}

const hashWithMD5 = (data) => {
    const md5 = require('md5')
    return md5(data)
}

const hashWithObjectHash = (data) => {
    const objectHash = require('object-hash')
    return objectHash.MD5(data)
} 

const hashWithCreateHash = (data) => {
    const createHash = require('create-hash')
    const hash = createHash('md5')
    hash.update(data)
    return hash.digest('hex')
}

const data = generateData()
hashData('md5', hashWithMD5, data)
hashData('object-hash', hashWithObjectHash, data)
hashData('create-hash', hashWithCreateHash, data)
```

Comment: Can you try passing encoding option to objectHash.MD5 function like: return objectHash.MD5(data, {encoding: 'hex'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object-hash` hashes the object, not the string value. The [implementation](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/blob/03f0f7ff417398983293912712e3a8b868ad5b0e/index.js#L304-L307) prepends

```
'string:' + string.length + ':'
```

to the input string and does an MD5 hash of that. You can confirm this by modifying `hashWithCreateHash` to generate a hash of the same input:

```
const hashWithCreateHash = (data) => {
    const createHash = require('create-hash')
    const hash = createHash('md5')
    hash.update(`string:${data.length}:${data}`) // instead of hash.update(data)
    return hash.digest('hex')
}
```

```
Hashing data with 'create-hash' library...
         Hash: f046296e8016b5632e6a1d1ebc885892
         Duration: 0.023s
```

Comment: How annoying! Thanks!

Comment: @ThisRestlessPilgrim Well, if you want to hash something as md5, you shouldn't expect that everyone uses the same hash - so search for an md5 library, not some random hashing library.

Comment: @ThisRestlessPilgrim keep in mind that speed isn't all that matters. Asynchronous implementations that don't block the event loop but take slightly longer would be much preferable to implementations that are blocking for the duration of the execution.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative to md5 since its memory usage blows up when I send large files through it. Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW, I've just raised a related question to which you might know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982969/hashing-a-string-vs-hashing-a-uint8array