# Hashing a string vs Hashing a UInt8Array

Tags: node.js, hash, md5

I'm comparing the performance of two MD5 libraries. When I send them both a string, they return the same hash:

```
     Hashing data with 'md5' library...
             Hash: d8b1e68f2f36743cdf302ed36f9347dc
             Duration: 0.003s

     Hashing data with 'create-hash' library...
             Hash: d8b1e68f2f36743cdf302ed36f9347dc
             Duration: 0.003s
```

However, when I send them the same UInt8Array, they give me different hashes:

```
     Hashing data with 'md5' library...
             Hash: 77fcf76d3f8c6a0f685f784d7ca6c642
             Duration: 0.001s

     Hashing data with 'create-hash' library...
             Hash: 0ee0646c1c77d8131cc8f4ee65c7673b
             Duration: 0s
```

Why does this happen?

```
const hashData = (name, hashingFunction, data) => {
    console.log(`\t Hashing data with '${name}' library...`)
    const start = new Date()
    const hash = hashingFunction(data)
    const end = new Date()
    console.log(`\t\t Hash: ${hash}`)
    const duration = (end - start) / 1000
    console.log(`\t\t Duration: ${duration}s`)
    console.log()
}

const runHashes = (data) => {
    const hashWithMD5 = (data) => {
        const md5 = require('md5')
        return md5(data)
    }

    const hashWithCreateHash = (data) => {
        return require('create-hash')('md5').update(data).digest('hex')        
    }

    hashData('md5', hashWithMD5, data)
    hashData('create-hash', hashWithCreateHash, data)
}

console.log('*** Running hashes on strings... *** \n')
runHashes("I want you to hash me...")

console.log('*** Running hashes on UInt8Array... *** \n')
runHashes(new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

Comment: Teach a man to fish... don't be afraid to look in the black box! Grab your debugger, and step through each call. Try to figure it out yourself before asking others to do it for you.

Comment: I can step into the `md5(...)` call, but the debugger won't going into the calls for *create-hash*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`md5` module API documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5#api), the hashing function accepts either a `String` or a `Buffer`. Your input of `Uin8Array` is neither, so I'm guessing the behavior of the hashing is going to be relatively undefined in comparison to the well-defined output given correctly typed input.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't know all these new fancy JavaScript types well.